# Customizing Map in raphaeljs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, svg, raphael

I am trying to construct a customized map in **raphaeljs**, in this i want do is, making it like a fadein fadeout effect of the countries that appear sequentially, for it i have used `setInterval()` Event...

I have tried some stuff right here but it manages to show the last item, it fadein fadeout...
I want to show that sequentially.... Can anyone help???

Here is the sample:-

http://jsfiddle.net/vpmzT/

Comment: Your code calls all of the states sequentially but with no interval. The interval is actually after calling every state, until it calls them all again. Is that what you really want? Call 1-7 -> wait 2 seconds -> call 1-7 again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're several issues here, the first one @JSantos has already pointed out: you set all the states to blink simultaneously, which is probably not the intended behavior.
Second problem is that the `current` variable, as well as the `intervalFunctions`, is shared, and therefore get assigned a new value for each state. This is why you get only the last state in the list to actually perform the animation -- by the time the animation starts the `intervalFunctions` array contains the animation functions for the last state.

There're multiple possible ways of working around this, but generally you'll have to schedule the animations to run sequentially by using `setTimeout(setInterval(animation_function(), total_interval), delay)`. One possible (though not very readable) way of doing that is http://jsfiddle.net/uTtaP/28/